# Can I set AuthenticatedUser in a MobileFirst 8 adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

If use the `securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser();` command in a javascript adapter I get the authenticated user.

Is there a method to set the authenticated user object in order to include certain attributes (like setActiveUser in MobileFirst 7) ?

If not, how can session objects be stored? is `WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().setAttribute` still working in MobileFirst 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, only security checks can set the authenticated user.

Also, 8.0 is session-independent, so there is no `getSession`.

In Java adapters, you can use

```
@Context
AdapterSecurityContext securityContext;
securityContext.getClientRegistrationData()
```

To get data attached to the current client ID.

You can then use `storeClientRegistrationData` to update this registration data.
This registration data is meant to be for lightweight data that relates to the security.
For anything else, you are expected to use some external database or data storage. You could use the client ID as they key.

In JavaScript adapters you can also `getTokenIntrospectionData`. You cannot set any attributes. So you need to use an external storage.

Comment: No session?? Imagine that a javascript adapter makes a back end call to recieve sensitive data about a customer and the call has a customer_Id as an input. (MF 7 we would get that customer_id from the login back end service and store it in session or in active user in order to later validate that the a user can request data that only belong to him by comparing if customer_id in request is the same with the one he has in his server session). Without a session how can we validate that ? There has to be something that I am missing here.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the use case, but you have access to the ClientID and the UserID in the introspection data, in the security check, the adapters, the client etc.